# Can't style my React Components by Class Name in Storybook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, sass, storybook

I'm not able to style my react components in storybook by their class name!

If I use a generic element like `div`,`<h1>` etc then I can style something. It has to be something with my webpack config but I just don't know what.

My `rules.js` that get's passed into `webpack.config.js`

`rules.js`

```
const { configureBabel } = require('../_babel.config');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const path = require('path');

/**
 * @param themePaths {ThemePaths}
 * @param selectMode {SelectMode}
 * @param selectTarget {SelectTarget}
 * @returns {*[]}
 */
function rules(themePaths, selectMode, selectTarget) {
    const babelOptions = configureBabel(selectMode, selectTarget);
    const babelEnvDeps = require('webpack-babel-env-deps');
    return [
        {
            test: /\.graphql$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'graphql-tag/loader',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            include: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'server'),
                path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'runtime'),
                themePaths.src,
                themePaths.generated,
                path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'swagger'),
                path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', 'debug'),
                babelEnvDeps.include(),
            ],
            // exclude: [/node_modules/],
            test: /\.(ts|tsx|mjs|js|svg|graphql)$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: babelOptions,
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            test: [/\.scss$/],
            use: [
                selectMode({ development: 'style-loader' }),
                selectMode({ production: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader }),
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                        importLoaders: 1,
                        localIdentName: '[name]-[local]-[hash:base64:3]',
                        modules: true,
                    },
                },
                {
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                    options: {
                        data: `
                        @import "_vars";
                        @import "_mixins";
                        @import "_normalize";
                        @import "_reset";
                        `,
                        includePaths: ['src/scss'],
                    },
                },
                {
                    loader: 'postcss-loader',
                    options: {
                        ident: 'postcss',
                        plugins: [require('autoprefixer')()],
                    },
                },
                'resolve-url-loader',
            ].filter(Boolean),
        },
        {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|svg|gif)$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {},
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            test: /\.(woff2?)$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[path][name].[ext]',
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
    ];
}

module.exports.rules = rules;
```

My `webpack.config.js`

```
const { resolve } = require('path');

module.exports = (baseConfig, env, defaultConfig) => {
    const rulesFn = require('../.webpack/rules').rules;
    const rules = rulesFn(
        {
            outputLegacy: '',
            generated: '',
            output: '',
            src: '',
        },
        input => input['development'],
        input => input['modern'],
    );
    delete rules[1].include;
    defaultConfig.module.rules = rules;
    defaultConfig.resolve.extensions = ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'];
    defaultConfig.resolve.alias = {
        ...(defaultConfig.resolve.alias || {}),
        swagger: resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'swagger'),
    };

    return defaultConfig;
};
```

My `config.ts`

```
import { configure } from "@storybook/react";

const req = require.context('../src/', true, /.stories.tsx$/);

function loadStories() {
    req.keys().forEach((filename) => req(filename))
}

configure(loadStories, module);
```

My React component `EateryItem.tsx`

```
import React from "react";
import "./EateryItem.scss";

export const EateryItem: React.SFC<any> = props => {
  return (
    <div className="Eatery" key={props.id}>
      <h3 className="name">{props.name}</h3>
      <p className="address">{props.address}</p>
      <p className="type">{props.foodType}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

My `EateryItem.scss` which I can seem to style these by class namme

```
.Eatery {
    border: 5px dashed $color-primary;
    margin: $base-spacing;
}

.name {
    background: red;
}
```

Not sure why I can't style these classnames?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I ended up realising after inspecting the classnames in the injected .js file from my storybook webpack that it was hashing the class names.

I went into my `rules.js` and switched off css modules by setting it to `false`.

```
loader: 'css-loader',
options: {
  importLoaders: 1,
  localIdentName: '[name]-[local]-[hash:base64:3]',
  modules: false,
},
```

It then stopped hashing the `className`s and it started to work!

Comment: Where is your rules file located? Is this something you have written.

Comment: Yeah you can check out my repo here it's in a separate `.webpack` folder. I've made the boilerplate for this available for everyone https://github.com/hghazni/killer-storybook-config

Comment: Thank you. I ended up going through hell the last couple of days, but I have bookmarked your github, thank you.